# gwt getting abosulte path on server side

Tags: gwt, path, server-side

Iam trying since 1 hour to get the absolute path of a file  ony server side:

```
   String path =  request.getRequestURL();

JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(path+"/test.jrxml",path+"/test.jasper");
```

this didnt work my expection is :

not found : http\12.0.0.13:8080]\test\test.jrxml  wrong syntax in dataname...etc

Comment: where is your file placed on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one in your `RemoteServiceServlet` class to get the `absolute path` of any resources placed under `war` directory that will be actually the path of server directory when deployed on server.

```
String pngFullPath = this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getServletContext()
        .getRealPath("images/1.png");
System.out.println(pngFullPath);


String icoFullPath = this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getServletContext()
        .getRealPath("favicon.ico");
System.out.println(icoFullPath);
```

output:

```
D:\Workspace\GWTProject\war\images\1.png
D:\Workspace\GWTProject\war\favicon.ico
```

Now change it as per the placement of `test.jrxml` file in your project.

here is the project structure:

[image]

Comment: http:\12.0.0.13:8080\test\test.jrxml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) –

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. What have your tried? What is the result?

Answer (score 2):

This is the method I use:

```java
public static String getServerBase(HttpServletRequest req)
{
    String scheme = req.getScheme(); // http
    String serverName = req.getServerName(); // sub.domain.ac.uk
    int serverPort = req.getServerPort(); // 80
    String contextPath = req.getContextPath(); // /MyApp

    return scheme + "://" + serverName + ":" + serverPort + contextPath;
}
```

Then simply append your file name.

Comment: Is it for absolute path of the file?

Comment: @Braj It's the absolute URL to the file. Not entirely sure what OP is asking for.

Comment: http:\12.0.0.13:8080\test\test.jrxml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: @user3110458 Where do the backslashes come from?

Comment: maybe from my JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile() i dont know

Comment: @user3110458 So, do you want the absolute URL to a file or the absolute path on your server to the file? And did you try any of the two answers?

Comment: the absolute URL or Path both would do it : i also tryed it with  :         InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test/test.jrxml"); 
   JasperCompileManager.compileReport(in); ----- didnt work i get the same error... Dont know why but slashes become backslashes and always one backslahs is missing in the "http:\\ <---

Comment: @user3110458 Is the path correct before you hand it over to `JasperCompileManager`?

Comment: hm no it isnt right, the HTTP request changes them i guess

Comment: @user3110458 Is that the case with your code or with the code from one of our answers?

Comment: @user3110458 Ok, `JasperCompileManager` is trying to use the source to create a `File`. In this case you'll need @Braj 's answer.