# GWT Java - image - include the path to a default image not working

Tags: java, image, gwt

I want to include a default image for the creation of a record. I have investigated the web and included this code;

```
        // Attach the image viewer to the document
        flexTable_1.setWidget(0, 0, panelImages);
        panelImages.setSize("150px", "150px");
        flexTable_1.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(0, 0, 6);
        panelImages.clear();
        imageYM.setWidth("75px");
        panelImages.add(imageYM);
        flexTable_1.setWidget(0, 0, panelImages);
        imagePath = GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"war\\YouthMember.gif";
```

The YouthMemer.gif is stored in AwardTracker_N --> war

The image is displayed; however, when I try to insert the row into the database table using imagePath I get the error in the log "Errors occurred in createYouthMember: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\localhost:8080\awardtracker_n\org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker\war\YouthMember.gif "

Answer (score 0):

Try use GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() instead.

Comment: Hi Christian, exactly the same is returned. I notice that the start is "http:\localhost" instead of "http:\\localhost" could this be the problem? If yes then how do I get it to return the "\\"?

Comment: Where du you see the address with only one "\" ? In Gwt debug  mode or on server side?
The character "\" is an escape sign in Java, if you want one "\" you have to make the string "\\". Maybe you need some kind of escape function.

Comment: Hi Christian, as per my post, it is in the log - "Errors occurred in createYouthMember: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\localhost:8080\awardtracker_n\org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker\war\YouthMember.gif "

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to display the image as I have done here and set the path to the image as null. If the user selects their own image then pass that path to the Server side. On the Server side check if the path is null; if it is then get the path to the default image as per this post: [gwt getting abosulte path on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475589/gwt-getting-abosulte-path-on-server-side)